# Accessing the control of shared layout page to other view page;i.e :button control

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I have a button/Action Link in Layout page.I need to call this button from different view pages as different purposes

//This is my layout page button

```
 <Button ID="lnkPrint"  class="btn btn-success printBtn okBtn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-print asitGlyp"></span></Button>
```

//I want to use it index view page.

Comment: You can get the element by ID either using JS Or JQuery. Have you tried that?

Comment: I did not try this.But how,Would you please explain?

Comment: If you're looking for a solutions using JS you should tag the question accordingly